# How to write a python subprocess script that waits for a server response?

Tags: python, shell, server, subprocess, response

Is there a way to write a python script that spawns a subprocess which calls and then waits for a server response before calling shell commands?

I need to log into a server on one terminal, then interact with another server in a separate window, and in that separate window I need to wait for a response.

I know I can run a separate file with a subprocess, but for the assignment I'm doing I need to only use one file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some `WAIT_KEY` which indicates that you are waiting for the server's response and run a *while loop* with `time.sleep` for saving resources. It should also work well if you process smth in a separate `thread`.

```
import time

while WAIT_KEY:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

P.S. Instead of `WAIT_KEY` you should call the method which returns the state of server's responce.
P.P.S. The smaller sleeping time you pick the more resources will be wasted in the `while` loop